# Rails 3 Observer -- looking to learn how to implement an Observer for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following Observer:

```
class NewsFeedObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :photo, :comment

  def after_create(record)
  end
end
```

What'd I'd like to learn how to do is add a SWITCH/IF statement in the after_create, so I know which model was created

Something like:

```
after_create(record)
switch model_type
case "photo"
 do some stuff
case "comment"
 do some other stuff
end
```

Or easier to visualize:

```
if record == 'Photo'
```

How can I take record, and determine the model name?

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, I notice you found this works using `record.class.name` but that's not very idiomatic Ruby. The Ruby `case` statement uses `===` for comparison which will work perfectly for you if you implement it properly.

```
class NewsFeedObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :photo, :comment

  def after_create(record)
    case record
      when Photo
        # do photo stuff
      when Comment
        # do comment stuff
      else
        # do default stuff
    end
  end
end
```

This essentially converts to:

```
if Photo === record
  # do photo stuff
elsif Comment === record
  # do comment stuff
else
  # do default stuff
end
```

---

I advise you to note the following:

```
class Sample
end

s = Sample.new

Foo === s   # true   uses Class#===
s === Foo   # false  uses Object#===
```

`===` is implemented differently in `Class` and `Object`

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup separate observers for separate models

So for User => UserObserver , Photo => PhotoObserver

You need to tell the rails app what observers to use, that you specify in config/environment.rb

Atleast this is the standard way. For more details

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers

Comment: This actually worked... "record.class.name" it would be nice to find a way to also get the action... CREATE, UDPATE, etc...