# DRYup shared model validations on before_destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, callback, dry

To prevent removal of related records, I am applying the before_destroy callbacks approach on each model

I defined several related-records validation methods in a module, so that they can be shared to different models' before_destroy callbacks:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RelatedModels
  before_destroy :has_courses
  ...
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RelatedModels
  before_destroy :has_courses
  ...
end

module RelatedModels

  def has_courses
    if self.courses.any?
      self.errors[:base] << "You cannot delete this while associated courses exists"
      return false
    end
  end

  def has_reports
    if self.reports.any?
      self.errors[:base] << "You cannot delete this while associated reports exists"
      return false
    end
  end

  def has_students
    if self.students.any?
      self.errors[:base] << "You cannot delete this while associated students exists"
      return false
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

But it doesn't looks very DRY

Any idea how to do it in a single method?
Meta-programming it's not among my skills

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an [`observer class`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html)

These are depreciated in Rails 4 (you have to use the [`rails-observers` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers)), but seem to be still part of the Rails 3 core

---

**Observer Classes**

"Listen" to specified actions in your model, and provide extended functionality. As stated by their documentation, they are particularly good for de-cluttering your models, allowing you to combine a lot of functionality into one central set of functions

Here's what you might want to do (please bare in mind I have only used these in Rails 4):

```
class RelatedObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :teachers, :school

  def before_destroy(record)
      associations = %w(teachers schools reports)
      associations.each do |association|
          if record.send(association).any?
              self.errors[:base] << "You cannot delete this while associated #{association.pluralize} exists"
              return false
          end
      end
  end
end
```

Here's a [good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836127/rails-3-observer-looking-to-learn-how-to-implement-an-observer-for-multiple-m) for you